# javascript string.replace target can execute a function?

Tags: javascript

I played with the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Visit Microsoft!";
document.write(str.replace("Microsoft",function (a){return a+"1111"}));

</script>
```

and the answer is :

```
Visit Microsoft1111!
```

How can it be working ?

I didnt see any documented code about it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well documented, e.g. at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Comment: w3schools is probably one of the worst reference ever, just as bad as MSDN used to be. I would stick with MDN.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yeah, w3schools is pretty bad. See http://w3fools.com/ for some informative ranting on the topic, and links to some better resources. :-)